# Unable to receive GCM notification?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an android app in which i am using GCM to recieve notification from my php server and i got this response from server i-e:-

> "multicast_id": 7015234441922271670,"success": 1,"failure":
>   0,"canonical_ids": 0,"results": [{"message_id":
>   "0:1344007383866721%2adac3a0ad8b3148"}]

I tried almost every solution by googling but still not able to receive `GCM`notification on my device, i tried conforming again and again that whether i put correct project id, Google server api key but still same problem please help me.

Mainefest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.informaluser.eaas"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

     <permission
        android:name="com.informaluser.eaas.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

     <permission
        android:name="com.informaluser.eaas.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

     <uses-permission android:name="com.informaluser.eaas.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="com.informaluser.eaas.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.informaluser.eaas.Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name="com.informaluser.eaas.Map"
                  android:label="Map of EAAS"></activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.informaluser.eaas.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.informaluser.eaas" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.informaluser.eaas.GcmIntentService" />

    <!-- Google Maps API Key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="My key" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

GCM BroadCast Reciever

```
package com.informaluser.eaas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);


    }

}
```

GCM intentService

```
package com.informaluser.eaas;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService{
    Context context;
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

         if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

             if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                            extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                    // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                                + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    // Post notification of received message.
                    //sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                    sendNotification(msg);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
                }
            }
         GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent myintent = new Intent(this, Map.class);
        myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Php Code

```
else if ($tag == 'msgsend') {

    $msg = $_POST['msg'];

    $reg = array("APA91bEk8ONc-En6wFZ6nawReKl-5xlTiRy9OOYx8731wnG0Cdp7EBqlwqguK_m3q-rCSytiEzukEMoOued_Nzb2UPPn4z46N4HuG6j93Jqbx47XwA");

            $notify = $db->send_push_notification($reg,$msg);
          if($notify!=false){

            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["user"]["msg"] = $user["msg"];
            echo json_encode($response);
            }
        else {

            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "JSON Error occured";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
}
```

send_push_notification function

```
function send_push_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {


        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => array("message" => $message),
        );
        // Google Cloud Messaging GCM API Key
        define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "My Google Console Server Key");

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        //print_r($headers);
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        return $result;
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));

        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Do you see anything in the logcat when you send the message?

Comment: @Eran yes this {"multicast_id":4789513855634684706,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1399217879762829%f9286410f9fd7ecd"}]}

Comment: No, that's the response you got at your server. You should send the message while your android device is connected to your computer, and see if you get anything in the log of the device.

Comment: @Eran when i send message i got no response on log of device

Comment: @Eran now i have checked i receive this response on my device but no notification appears 

"I/GCM Demo(1518): Working... 1/5 @ 1230455 I/GCM Demo(1518): Working... 2/5 @ 1230958 I/GCM Demo(1518): Working... 3/5 @ 1231459 I/GCM Demo(1518): Working... 4/5 @ 1231961 I/GCM Demo(1518): Working... 5/5 @ 1232463 I/GCM Demo(1518): Completed work @ 1232964 I/GCM Demo(1518): 0.0 I/GCM Demo(1518): Received: Bundle[{message=0.0, android.support.content.wakelockid=1, collapse_key=do_not_collapse, from=31292454533}]"

Comment: From your logcat, it look like the message reaches your device. Is the text of your message supposed to be "0.0" as seen in the log? Are you sure you don't see any notification?

Comment: @Eran yes for testing purpose i sent "0.0" as a message, and no i double check many times but not able to receive any notification sadly

Comment: @Eran now i am getting notification but they are arriving very late

Comment: @Eran anyways thanks a lot for your response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my mistake what I'm doing in my code is in  `GcmIntentService` i comment out `.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)` so that's the reason even after receiving message i was not able to see the notification.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
```